# How to create an editable table with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs. I am trying to create a table with inputs like below,

```
<table className="table table-bordered table-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          {gameList.map((game)=>{
            return (
              <th key={game.id}>{game.game_type}</th>
            )
          })}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {roundList.map((round)=>{
          return(
            <tr key={round.id}>
              <td>{round.game_round}</td>
              {gameList.map((game)=>{
                return (
                    <td key={game.id}>
                      <input type="text"/>
                    </td>
                  )
                })
              }
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image: The table]

How do I get all input values by gameId and roundId accordingly?

Comment: I suggest to use a library like `react-hook-form` that makes form handling with complex data structures way easier.

Comment: You could create a `handleChange` and passing the `round.id` and `game.id` with the input value to update the correct round and game. But if the `game.id` is unique that should be enough already.

Answer (score 0):

---

---

Hi, If i may notice You are trying to use pure Js in reactJS :). If you want to use same semantic as above lets than add some hooks ;)

```
const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({});

<table className="table table-bordered table-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          {gameList.map((game)=>{
            return (
              <th key={game.id}>{game.game_type}</th>
            )
          })}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {roundList.map((round, index)=>{
          return(
            <tr key={round.id}>
              <td>{round.game_round}</td>
              {gameList.map((game, ind)=>{
                return (
                    <td key={game.id}>
                      <input 
                       type="text" 
                       value={inputValues?.[`${round.id}`]?.[`${game.id}`]} 
                       onChange={(event) => {
                       setInputValues(old => ({...old, [`${round.id}`]: {...old[`${round.id}`], [`${game.id}`]: event.target.value}}))                     
                      }/>
                    </td>
                  )
                })
              }
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

now you have state inputValues for all input values in one object, so you can access them by order.id and game.id.

This is one solutions based on your html structure above, but i strongly recommend to You to create separate Input component, your own controlled component and than to use it maybe in form, than you will have all values in onSubmit form function :)

Comment: can you show me the best approach with a minimal example with my original requirement?